# Change Newsletter Field, Border, and size of button

Tags: css, colors

I have a newsletter signup form on my website and I'm trying to change the color of the field of the form, the border, and the size of the button. My website is zekemaurer.com. Trying to figure it out in CSS but it's not working

Answer (score 0):

refer this link to change the color of the text field of the form and change border color-->
https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_form.asp